# Structure of the torus of the Active Galactic Nucleus

Tags: galaxy, accretion-discs, galaxy-center, active-galaxy

How much do we know about the structure of the torus surrounding the [Active Galactic Nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_galactic_nucleus) (AGN)? Is the shape defined or still under speculations? And are there different structures for this torus possible i.e., does it vary from galaxy to galaxy?

Comment: stp30 you've been asking a lot of general questions about AGN recently; it may be best to wait until you have a more specific question in mind. For example, typing 'AGN Torus' in to google gives a number of recent papers and discussions about the range of shapes of torii observed and theorised in the past decade

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked more roughly 8 years ago, and for 2 years there is a review article around which I found worth mentioning and summarizing. The manuscript is called *[Redefining the torus:  A unifying view of AGN in the infrared and sub mm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.08639)* and work of [Sebastian Florian Hönig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_F._H%C3%B6nig). Here an excerpt of the abstract:

> The advent of high-angular resolution IR and sub-mm interferometry allows for spatially-resolvedobservations  of  the  parsec-scale  environment  of  active  galactic  nuclei  (AGN),  commonly  referred  toas the “torus.”  While molecular lines show the presence of large, massive disks, the IR observationsappear to be dominated by a strong polar component that has been interpreted.

The main result seems to be the following schematic picture (Fig. 4 of the manuscript) of the AGN which is an overlay of various observations:

[image: Fig 4 of arXiv:1909.08639]

1. The purple ring are observations in the near-IR.
2. The yellow torus and the gray dashed lines are from ${\rm H}_2$ emission.
3. The main brownish cone is from mid-IR.
4. The redish wobbly plane with the red (solid) arrows and the purple (dashed) arrows are sub-mm obseravtions (${\rm CO/HCN/HCO^+}$)
5. Bright green dots on the $x$-axis are ${\rm H_2 O}$ maser emissions.